# Job To Send Email Every Evening in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have figured out the sql statement to email information that I specify. What I cannot figure out is how to create a sql server job that will send me this email at specific periods of time. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Management Studio:

1. Open Object Explorer (F8).
2. Connect to your server.
3. Expand the server node.
4. Expand SQL Server Agent.
5. Right-click jobs, select New Job...
6. Give the job a unique name.
7. Go to the Steps tab.
8. Click New...
9. Give the step a name and enter your command (e.g. `EXEC someproc;`).
10. Click OK.
11. Go to the Schedules tab.
12. Click New...
13. Give the schedule a name (e.g. `Nightly`).
14. Change "Frequency" to Occurs: "daily".
15. Change "Daily Frequency" to Occurs once at: [desired time].
16. Click OK.
17. Click OK.

To make sure it works, you can right-click the Jobs node, select Refresh, then right-click the job you just created, and select "Start Job at Step..."

Answer (score 2):

Create a new SQL Server job. Add a step to execute the SQL statement. Add a new schedule to run as you need. If you right-click the jobs in Management Studio, a rather self-explanatory  GUI/wizard will open to create a new job.